# How to start spring batch job on rest call from UI with parameters

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring-boot

I am newbie to spring batch. I wants to start spring batch job on button click. I am passing jobDTO and id from UI to Java controller. My Java controller based on jobDTO and id do further processing of starting job. I have to do the same thing with spring batch how do I achieve this?
below is my java controller code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response<JobDTO> createJobInstance(@RequestBody JobDTO jobDTO,
        @PathVariable("Id") long id) throws Exception {
    return execService.createNewJobInstance(context, id, jobeDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow spring batch documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#runningJobsFromWebContainer)

```
@Controller
public class JobLauncherController {

  @Autowired
  JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  Job job;

  @RequestMapping("/jobLauncher.html")
  public void handle() throws Exception{
     jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
  }
}
```